# How can I add a Node to an HBox inside of a Tab JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, tabs

I have a GUI that I've created, and I would like to add a `ProgressIndicator`when the application is doing something in the background. I've created a `Tab` in the constructor similar to the following:

```
public class myGUI {
    Tab myTab;

    myGUI() {
        myTab = new Tab("My Tab");

        HBox view = new HBox();
        VBox left = new VBox();
        BorderPane right = new BorderPane();

        /*A lot of other things are declared that go in left and right*/

        view.getChildren().addAll(left, right);
        myTab.setContent(view);
    }
...
```

Later on, I have a button press that starts the application doing a background task, and I would like to add a `ProgressIndicator` to the center of the `BorderPane`. I tried something like the following:

```
private void handleMyAction(MouseEvent e) {
    myTab.getContent().getChildren().get(1).setCenter(new ProgressIndicator(-1.0f));
}
```

I would think that this works, however, `getContent` returns a `Node`, and I cannot call `getChildren` on that `Node`. How can I access the `BorderPane` to add another `Node` without making the `BorderPane` a field in my class?

Comment: Why don't you just make the `BorderPane` an instance variable, instead of a local variable?

Comment: I could, I just feel like that's a sloppy solution, that's why I specified it in the question, but your are right, that is what I will be doing if I cannot find another way to do it.

Comment: I missed that last sentence. I don't really see why you consider that "sloppy" though.

Comment: It adds possibly unnecessary fields to the Class.

Comment: It adds an additional field, but why is that an issue? It is part of the implementation of `MyGUI` (just as `myTab` is).

Comment: `myTab` is already a field, and as a result, I believe that `right` is an unnecessary field, since I should be able to access `right` by calling methods in `myTab`. It's really just being picky, but I was looking to see if I could find an answer.

Comment: I don't think I understand the point of making your code more complex in order to reduce the number of fields in a class. That just sounds like you're aiming for a bad coding style, almost deliberately. If you really want to do it, you just need to add the correct downcasts to your code.

Comment: I ended up going with this.

Answer (score 1):

Just make the border pane an instance variable:

```
public class MyGUI {
    private Tab myTab;
    private BorderPane right ;

    MyGUI() {
        myTab = new Tab("My Tab");

        HBox view = new HBox();
        VBox left = new VBox();
        right = new BorderPane();

        /*A lot of other things are declared that go in left and right*/

        view.getChildren().addAll(left, right);
        myTab.setContent(view);
    }

    private void handleMyAction(MouseEvent e) {
        right.setCenter(new ProgressIndicator(-1.0f));
    }
}
```